# QB not returning TxnLineID on ReceivePaymentToDepositQuery

Tags: qbxml

I'm trying to automate deposits for a client who has 1000's of undeposited payments. Adding a deposit requires the TxnID and TxnLineID from the payment. However when I query payments to deposit, it's returning null for the TxnLineID. All the other fields look fine, so I must be doing something right. There's nothing weird about my query:

```
IReceivePaymentToDepositQuery query = reqSet.AppendReceivePaymentToDepositQueryRq();
```

Then later on when I'm picking apart the results:

```
if (ptdRet.TxnLineID != null) pmt.TxnLineID = ptdRet.TxnLineID.GetValue();
```

TxnLineID is always null. Again, all the other fields look fine. What am I doing wrong? I've studied the programmer's guide (section about payments and deposits) and the OSR but can't figure it out. I've also tried explicitly setting IncludeRetElementList. I'd love to hear from somebody who has actually got this to work.

I'm using QBFC12 and Premier 2014 (but I've also tested with Enterprise v12 and several different company files).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include the TxnLineID, just the TxnID. Here's my request:

```
IDepositAdd dep = MsgRequest.AppendDepositAddRq();
dep.TxnDate.SetValue(DateTime.Today);
dep.DepositToAccountRef.FullName.SetValue("Checking");
IDepositLineAdd line = dep.DepositLineAddList.Append();
line.ORDepositLineAdd.PaymentLine.PaymentTxnID.SetValue("TxnIDGoesHere");
```

Comment: Has this actually worked for you? I tried it and got an error indicating that it also needs the TxnLineID. This is supported by the programmer's reference guide, which is very clear on this point.

Comment: I coded a simple example using a QB Sample company file that had two payments to deposit and was able to get it to work. I tested with one payment per deposit and the two payments on one deposit. Both worked correctly. If you'd like, I can post the full sample code that I used.